# is it safe to rename an exe?

Tags: windows, rename

Of course, it's a given that if another program depends on the exe in question, it's a bad idea. But for something non-system and independent (an installer, a cli / gui tool), is there anything that could go wrong down the road?

Context: I have a collection of programs, installers and scripts, and it bothers me they all have different casing, and some contain special characters.

Comment: Its safe, I do it all the time with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, but this really only works for stand alone exes.  Anything that gets referenced by dlls, or puts down roots in AppData, or writes to the registry, or......etc. etc.  But simple lonely exes with no social life, go right ahead.

Comment: Would an exe that modifies appdata or the registry be unsafe to rename _before_ running it for the first time? Problem is most apps (even standalone and portable ones) do make registry modifications.

Answer (score 1):

No, not entirely safe.

An exe file can have hundreds of dependencies. Suppose, you have an exe file named D. D is used by application C. And C is used by processes A and B. Windows will not let you rename D when it is in use. But if A and B or C is not running and you rename D to anything else like E then C will not run. As a result A and B will also break down. If they are system processes (which run occasionally) then your system will likely crash. There are thousands of death factors for system which is disguising around. Like if you boot from a live linux media, then rename NT kernel (ntoskrnl.exe to damnkrnl.exe) or windows boot loader (winload.exe to junkload.exe) then windows will break down like a pillar of cards.

So it is safe to first if an exe file is standalone or dependent. You can use an excellent tool named Process explorer for this task. This tool will help you to see the applications and resources used by other processes, and that will help you to determine if an exe is in use by a critical process. The same think goes for dynamic link libraries or DLLs. They are also much more critical. Triple check before renaming an exe file.